Adding a time-out to console app in Java for user that takes too long
I am coding a hangman game using Java. I wanted to make things tougher so I added a timing condition for a user to guess the word (example:20 secs) now the problem I'm facing is that the while loop doesn't want to quit once the 20 secs are done. It keep on waiting for the user to enter their guess and then updates him that he lost and that's illogic since if you've already lost why would I keep waiting for your answer? I tried adding this line to break it since once the time is up the timeout variable will automatically change to true:
if (timeout) {   break; }
But it doesn't work!
Here is my code:
package hangman;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Essai {
    private static String[] fruits = {"straweberry","bananas","orange","apple",
            "watermelon","peach"};
    private static String[] countries = {"tunisia","spain","japan","qatar",
            "greece","palestine"};
    private static String[] animals = {"shark","wolf","cat","cow","snake",
            "horse"};
    private static String[] languages = {"arabic","korean","english","russian",
            "turkish","hindi"};
    private static String[] occupations = {"doctor","engineer","teacher",
            "baker","clown","pilot"};
    private static Scanner scanner;
    private static boolean timeout;
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";

    public static void hangman(int tries, String word) {
        if (tries == 1) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("___|___");
            System.out.println();
        }
        if (tries == 2) {
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("___|___");
        }
        if (tries == 3) {
            System.out.println("   ____________");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   | ");
            System.out.println("___|___");
        }
        if (tries == 4) {
            System.out.println("   ____________");
            System.out.println("   |          _|_");
            System.out.println("   |         /   \\");
            System.out.println("   |        |     |");
            System.out.println("   |         \\_ _/");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("___|___");
        }
        if (tries == 5) {
            System.out.println("   ____________");
            System.out.println("   |          _|_");
            System.out.println("   |         /   \\");
            System.out.println("   |        |     |");
            System.out.println("   |         \\_ _/");
            System.out.println("   |           |");
            System.out.println("   |           |");
            System.out.println("   |");
            System.out.println("___|___");
        }
        if (tries == 6) {
            System.out.println("   ____________");
            System.out.println("   |          _|_");
            System.out.println("   |         /   \\");
            System.out.println("   |        |     |");
            System.out.println("   |         \\_ _/");
            System.out.println("   |           |");
            System.out.println("   |           |");
            System.out.println("   |          / \\ ");
            System.out.println("___|___      /   \\");
        }
        if (tries == 7) {
            System.out.println("   ____________");
            System.out.println("   |          _|_");
            System.out.println("   |         /   \\");
            System.out.println("   |        |     |");
            System.out.println("   |         \\_ _/");
            System.out.println("   |          _|_");
            System.out.println("   |         / | \\");
            System.out.println("   |          / \\ ");
            System.out.println("___|___      /   \\");
            System.out.println("Game over! It was: " + word);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)) + 1;
        String word = null;
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                System.out
                        .println(ANSI_GREEN + "Category: fruits" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(
                        ANSI_GREEN + "Category: countries" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = countries[(int) (Math.random() * countries.length)];
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out
                        .println(ANSI_GREEN + "Category: animals" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = animals[(int) (Math.random() * countries.length)];
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println(
                        ANSI_GREEN + "Category: languages" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = languages[(int) (Math.random() * countries.length)];
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println(
                        ANSI_GREEN + "Category: occupations" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = occupations[(int) (Math.random() * countries.length)];
                break;
        }

        timeout = false;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                timeout = true;
            }
        }, 20 * 1000);

        // word="cat";
        int nb = word.length();
        String chl = word;
        char[] ch = new char[nb];
        String chf = "";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
            ch[i] = '-';
            chf = chf + '*';
        }

        System.out.println(
                ANSI_BLUE + "Word contains " + nb + " letters: " + ANSI_RESET);
        System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "You have 20 secs. Go!" + ANSI_RESET);
        int tries = 0;

        while (!timeout && tries < 7 && word.equals(chf) == false) {
            System.out.println("Current progress: " + new String(ch));

            // System.out.println(timeout);
            if (timeout) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.print(ANSI_RED + "\nGuess a letter: " + ANSI_RESET);

            char letter = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

            long remainingTime = (20 * 1000)
                    - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            System.out
                    .println("Time left: " + remainingTime / 1000 + " seconds");

            int pos = word.indexOf(letter);

            if (pos == -1) {
                System.out.println("\nWrong Guess!");
                tries++;
                hangman(tries, chl);
            } else {
                while (pos != -1) {
                    ch[pos] = letter;
                    word = word.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(letter), "*");
                    pos = word.indexOf(letter);
                }
            }
        }
        timer.cancel();

        if (timeout) {
            System.out.println("Time's up! You took too long to guess.");
        } else {
            if (word.equals(chf)) {
                System.out.print("Congratulations! You've guessed the word: "
                        + chl + "!");
            }
        }
    }
}


"But it doesn't work" is a misunderstanding about how your code works: it works exactly the way it's supposed to, and your while and if work just fine, your code just never gets to those checks because scanner.nextLine() is waiting for input. It's a blocking operation. So what you actually want to know is How to interrupt a java.util.Scanner nextLine call

Java I/O doesn't normally include timeout parameters, so they have to be interrupted by calling .interrupt() on the blocking thread. You'll need a thread for the timer with the thread to interupt as a field, and a run() method that just sleeps, then calls the interrupt. You can either create a dedicated input thread each time (they're cheap) and pass that to the timer thread, or pass Thread.currentThread() to the timer and use the regular blocking input. Either way, after the input returns, check .interrupted(), if true then the I/O did not complete.

By the way, a tip: text blocks

I suggest that you can find a solution in this answer by piegames. Does this answer your question? How to interrupt reading on System.in?

I have introduced the following changes:

Synchronization
lock variable for synchronization between the timeout thread and the main thread.

It works as follow:

The timeout thread sets the timeout flag to true and notifies the main thread using lock.notify()
The main thread waits for this notification using lock.wait() within the synchronized block. It continues execution only when the timeout occurs or the game ends.

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Essai {
    private static String[] fruits = {"strawberry", "bananas", "orange", "apple",
            "watermelon", "peach"};
    private static String[] countries = {"tunisia", "spain", "japan", "qatar",
            "greece", "palestine"};
    private static String[] animals = {"shark", "wolf", "cat", "cow", "snake",
            "horse"};
    private static String[] languages = {"arabic", "korean", "english", "russian",
            "turkish", "hindi"};
    private static String[] occupations = {"doctor", "engineer", "teacher",
            "baker", "clown", "pilot"};
    private static Scanner scanner;
    private static boolean timeout;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";

    public static void hangman(int tries, String word) {
        // The implementation of the hangman method remains the same
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
        String word = null;
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "Category: fruits" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = fruits[(int) (Math.random() * fruits.length)];
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "Category: countries" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = countries[(int) (Math.random() * countries.length)];
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "Category: animals" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = animals[(int) (Math.random() * animals.length)];
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "Category: languages" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = languages[(int) (Math.random() * languages.length)];
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "Category: occupations" + ANSI_RESET);
                word = occupations[(int) (Math.random() * occupations.length)];
                break;
        }

        timeout = false;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    timeout = true;
                    lock.notify(); // Notify the main thread about the timeout
                }
            }
        }, 20 * 1000);

        int tries = 0;
        String chf = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            chf += "*";
        }

        System.out.println(
                ANSI_BLUE + "Word contains " + word.length() + " letters: " + ANSI_RESET);
        System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "You have 20 secs. Go!" + ANSI_RESET);

        while (!timeout && tries < 7 && !word.equals(chf)) {
            System.out.println("Current progress: " + chf);

            if (timeout) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.print(ANSI_RED + "\nGuess a letter: " + ANSI_RESET);

            char letter = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

            int pos = word.indexOf(letter);

            if (pos == -1) {
                System.out.println("\nWrong Guess!");
                tries++;
                hangman(tries, word);
            } else {
                while (pos != -1) {
                    chf = chf.substring(0, pos) + letter + chf.substring(pos + 1);
                    pos = word.indexOf(letter, pos + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        timer.cancel();

        if (timeout) {
            System.out.println("Time's up! You took too long to guess.");
        } else {
            if (word.equals(chf)) {
                System.out.print("Congratulations! You've guessed the word: " + word + "!");
            }
        }
    }
}



thank you for your efforts. But it didn't fix the problem :(
